# Accessing an array in another view controller

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, nsarray, uicollectionviewcell

I have an array of NSObjects that I need to read in another viewcontroller. However I'm unsure what level I should be setting the data for it.

This screen shot below best explains what I'm trying to do. Each HomeController has a title, members list, description and inset collectionview (yellow bar). I need the collection views number of cells to equal the number of members.
[image: screenshot]

I tried creating a reference to HomeController inside the inset collectionview by using lazy var but that got the the error: 
`fatal error: Index out of range`

```
lazy var homeController: HomeController = {
    let hc = HomeController()
    hc.liveCell = self
    return hc
}()
```

Again this is done from within the inset collectionview

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath :
    IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: profileImageCellId, for: indexPath) as! profileImageCell

    let room = homeController.rooms[indexPath.row]

    print(room.members?.count)

    return cell

}
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Data is added to the array using this function

```
var rooms = [Room]()

func fetchAllRooms(){
    Database.database().reference().child("rooms").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let room = Room()

            room.rid = snapshot.key
            room.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

            self.rooms.append(room)
            print(snapshot)

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            })
        }


        print("end of room snap")

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Here is the cell for item at index path at the HomeController level

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell = UICollectionViewCell()
    let section = indexPath.section

    let liveCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: LiveCellId, for: indexPath) as! LiveCell

        let cell = liveCell

        let room = rooms[indexPath.row]

        liveCell.liveStreamNameLabel.text = room.groupChatName
        liveCell.descriptionLabel.text = room.groupChatDescription

        return cell
}
```

Comment: `let hc = HomeController()` creates a new instance of a HomeController. Maybe this isn't what you were aiming for? It won't give you the current HomeController object. So it really depends on how you create the rooms array.

Comment: @ryantxr that makes sense. That's probably why I got the index out of range error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the count of your array in order to prevent the crash `Index out of range`

```
if homeController.rooms.count > indexPath.row {
  let room = homeController.rooms[indexPath.row]
  print(room.members?.count)
}
```

Comment: what exactly does this do?

Comment: Just to avoid your crash

Answer (score 0):

Can you Debug and share below two things then we can look further on this

- Check whats the index path you are getting
- Check if your array have data

Comment: Checking `let room = homeController.rooms[indexPath.row]` there are two indices. Both return int value of zero.

Comment: This means the array is not having any data. So now next step we need to really debug how array is initialized in HomeController. As you are creating a new instance here to get the array data.

Comment: I included the function that creates the array in an edit on the post

Comment: Since you are initializing an empty array so every time you create new instance it will have blank rooms array and hence index out of range, better to call the fetchallrooms method also from the same instance OR have array defined in anotherView controller and set the value using HomeController and then access in collectionview delegate method using self.rooms[indexPath.row]

Comment: i'm sorry I'm a bit confused. HomeController is my main view controller. It controls how many cells I have and what their data is. The Cell is a uicollectionviewdatasource and both houses and provides information for the inset collectionview. My problem is accessing the information that is one level above the inset collection view at the cell level. Hope this clears things up. I will provide my `cellforitematindexpath` for each HomeController cell in case that helps.